# Bash regex test on two similar strings matches on one, not the other

Tags: regex, bash

A simple question, but I'm stumped. I'm trying to match several similar strings, eventually to get the captured groups. Here's the code:

```
$ my_regex="^# ([:alnum:]+): (.*)$"
$ [[ '# nl: nl-ams1-v1 - Amsterdam / Netherlands #1' =~ $my_regex ]] && printf "yes\n" || printf "no\n"
yes
$ [[ '# ca: ca-mon1-v1 - Montreal / Canada #1' =~ $my_regex ]] && printf "yes\n" || printf "no\n"
no
```

This should capture `nl` or `ca` and the description following the colon and space. Can anyone see the difference in the strings making the second fail? The spaces are really spaces and not tabs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have misspelled `[[:alnum:]]`. The outer square brackets mark this as a character class and the inner brackets are part of the name of this POSIX character class.

Just `[:alnum:]` is a plain character class which simply matches `:`, `a`, `l`, `n`, `u`, or `m` (the text inside the square brackets is merely a list of characters; duplicates are silently ignored)